# Ошибка сегментации при использовании WaveOut

Tags: c, winapi, segmentation-fault

Пытаюсь воспроизвести звук при помощи WaveOut. На данный момент набросал такой код:

```
int SoundPlayer_create(SoundPlayer *player,
                       unsigned long int sample_rate, unsigned int sample_size, unsigned int channels)
{
    player->format.nSamplesPerSec = sample_rate;
    player->format.wBitsPerSample = sample_size;
    player->format.nChannels = channels;

    player->format.nBlockAlign = channels * sample_size / 8;
    player->format.nAvgBytesPerSec = sample_rate * player->format.nBlockAlign;

    player->format.cbSize = 0;
    player->format.wFormatTag = WAVE_FORMAT_PCM;

    int err = waveOutOpen(&player->hndl,
                          WAVE_MAPPER, &player->format,
                          0, 0, CALLBACK_NULL);

    switch(err)
    {
        case MMSYSERR_NOERROR:      return 0;
        case MMSYSERR_ALLOCATED:    return -1;
        case MMSYSERR_BADDEVICEID:  return -2;
        case MMSYSERR_NODRIVER:     return -3;
        case MMSYSERR_NOMEM:        return -4;

        default:                    return -999;
    }
}

int SoundPlayer_playWave(SoundPlayer *player, void *wave_block, unsigned long wave_size)
{
    int err;

    WAVEHDR header;
    {
        memset(&header, 0, sizeof(header));
        header.dwBufferLength = wave_size;
        header.lpData = wave_block;

        err = waveOutPrepareHeader(player->hndl, &header, sizeof(WAVEHDR));
        switch(err)
        {
            case MMSYSERR_NOERROR:      break;
            case MMSYSERR_INVALHANDLE:  return -1;
            case MMSYSERR_NODRIVER:     return -2;
            case MMSYSERR_NOMEM:        return -3;

            default:                    return -999;
        }
    }

    err = waveOutWrite(player->hndl, &header, sizeof(WAVEHDR));

    switch(err)
    {
        case MMSYSERR_NOERROR:      return 0;
        case MMSYSERR_INVALHANDLE:  return -1;
        case MMSYSERR_NODRIVER:     return -2;
        case MMSYSERR_NOMEM:        return -3;

        default:                    return -999;
    }
}
```

Это, собственно, код "движка". Теперь код "клиента":

```
static SoundPlayer main_sound_player;
SoundPlayer_create(&main_sound_player, 44100, 16, 2);
{
    test_sound.data_size);
    unsigned char *test_wave = malloc(4096);
    memset(test_wave, 127, 4096);
    SoundPlayer_playWave(&main_sound_player, test_wave, 4096);
}
```

При вызове последней функции, при любом размере и содержимом буфера всегда воспроизводится сильный, один и тот же шум, а через несколько секунд тишины происходит ошибка сегментации. Воспроизводится стабильно, но иногда не вылетает.

Comment: А что происходит с `wave_block` после вызова `SoundPlayer_playWave`? Вы понимаете, что он должен "жить" до тех пор, пока не случится это: "When the buffer is finished, the WHDR_DONE bit is set in the dwFlags member of the WAVEHDR structure."? У Вас тут `WAVEHDR` вообще на стеке `SoundPlayer_playWave`. Это не может работать!

Comment: Что-то слишком сложно. Почему бы не использовать функцию PlaySound с параметром SND_MEMORY?

Comment: О, а ведь вы правы насчёт заголовка. Оказалось, что дело было именно в этом. Какая глупость...